# How coordinates of **P'** are (y, x)?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm learning Trigonometry right now and at current about trigonometry functions. I'm quite confused right now in a section of the chapter. Please have a look at the image below. [image: Image 1]

How triangle **OMP** and **OM'P'** are congruent? Both triangles are 90° but how sides of both the triangle are equal?  
 
Also how the coordinates of $P'$ are $(y, x)$. 
Sorry if I'm asking foolish questions. I have just started learning mathematics with my own. Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Try to write instead of $x,y$ some numbers, For example $5,3$. I think that will help.

Comment: from my understanding in triangle $OM'P'$ $OM'$ is perpendicular and $M'P'$ is base. Am I right?

Comment: the two lines OA and OA', by construction, are simmetric about the diagonal in the first quadrant. Besides  angle OP'M' = $\theta$ because the transversal OA' through the parallels OY and M'P'.

Answer (score 2):

OPM+POM=90° (Sum of angles of triangle=180° and PMO=90°)

So, OPM= 90°-POM=90°-theta=P'OM'      (i)

Similarly, OP'M'=POM     (ii)

OP=P'O (Given)     (iii)

Therefore OPM is congruent to P'OM'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How the coordinates of P' are (y, x)?

Comment: Because P'M'=OM and PM=OM'